# If chatacteristic of $K$ is positive, show that every homomorphism from additive group to multiplicative group maps all elements of $K$ to $1$

Tags: field-theory, group-homomorphism

Suppose $K$ is a field. Denote $(K,+)$ as the abelian group under addition operation and $(K,\times)$ as the abelian group under multiplication opearation. If the characteristic of $K$ is positive, show that every homomorphism $f:(K,+) \rightarrow (K,\times)$ maps all elements of $K$ to $1$.

I don't even know how to start this question. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the field $K$ has characteristic $p>0$, and consider a group homomorphism
$$
f\colon (K,+)\to (K\setminus\{0\},\times).
$$
For any element $x\in K$, we must have $px=0$. Applying the group homomorphism to this equation,
$$
f(x)^p=1.
$$
On the other hand, by the Binomial Theorem
$$
\begin{align*}
(f(x)-1)^p&=f(x)^p+\{\text{terms that are a multiple of $p$}\}+(-1)^p\\
&=f(x)^p+(-1)^p\\
&=1+(-1)^p\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
$$
The last line follows by considering the cases when $p$ is odd and when $p=2$ separately. Hence we've shown that $(f(x)-1)^p=0$. Since fields lack zero divisors, this implies $f(x)=1$. Consequently the homomorphism maps all elements to $1$.

Answer (score 3):

$f(p\cdot a)=f(0)=1$.  And $f(p\cdot a)=f(a)^p$.  So $f(a)^p=1$.  So $0=f(a)^p-1=(f(a)-1)^p$.  So $(f(a)-1)^p=0$. $K$ has no zero divisors so $f(a)-1=0$. So $f(a)=1$.

Comment: I think you may have a minor sign error...

Comment: @pre-kidney I think it's right.  $(-1)^p=-1$ in every characteristic.

Comment: I also used $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$ which is only true in characteristic $p$.  That's why this is not true in characteristic zero.  At least if it is true this proof will not prove it.

Comment: I suppose you're right, not sure why I felt like something was missing. By the way, it is not true in characteristic 0: just consider the exponential function mapping $(\mathbb R,+)\to (\mathbb R\setminus \{0\},\times)$.

Comment: @pre-kidney Ah the exponential, thanks for the counter-example, it didn't seem like it would be true in char $0$.